# Is possible to compare two different objects in java?

Tags: java, comparable

I wanted to compare object "name" attributes of different classes. Shall someone explain me how to do this? Here the code.

```
class Cat implements Comparable<Cat>{
String name;
Cat(){
  super();
}
Cat(String name){
  this.name = name;
}
@Override
 public int compareTo(Cat obj){
  return this.name.compareTo(obj.name);
 }
}
class Dog extends Cat{
 String name;
 Dog(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

public class Compare {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Cat oCat1 = new Cat("Meow");
   Cat oCat2 = new Cat("Purr");
   Dog oDog1 = new Dog("Rex");
  int result = oCat1.compareTo(oDog1);
   System.out.println(result);
 }
}
```

Comment: Have the classes share the same interface, one that has a `public String getName()` method.

Answer (score 1):

How about having this super class

```
class NamedPet implements Comparable<NamedPet> {

    private String name ;

    public NamedPet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(NamedPet otherPet){
        return this.name.compareTo(otherPet.name);
    }
}
```